# Private API and SMS content URI's on Android

Tags: java, android, api, sms

Without accessing private API's to get Content URI's, etc. for SMS, how are we expected to query this data? I am currently in the process of writing my own SMS app and I want to stay as compatible as possible. Without storing the information myself in my own database (such that I can store the text messages so that other programs can access the data when/if they delete my app) and without using private API's how the heck are we suppose to query SMS data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Without accessing private API's to get Content URI's, etc. for SMS, how are we expected to query this data?

You are not expected to query that data at all.

"That data" is not part of the operating system. It is part of whatever SMS client the user happens to use. That might be the open source Messenger app, for which Google has declined to provide a documented and supported API. That might be whatever SMS client a device manufacturer has put on the device, which may or may not have a documented and supported API and may or may not be using the Google client's content provider.

Comment: I had a feeling that was how it was going to be. So, to be kosher I should be stuffing my data into my own database?

Comment: @Shadow: Until such time as Google makes the SMS content provider part of the OS, I would not assume the SMS content provider is the right answer. Now, you might want to try to detect to see if that content provider exists, and if it does give the user a choice of where to store stuff. That too raises issues, such as what happens when Google changes the provider and you have users who chose the provider option and then get an OTA update to one where the provider changed.

Comment: you raise a good point. This will be a most interesting adventure indeed :) Thank's CommonsWare!